# bootstrap collapsable nav button not clickable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a collapsable menu working on a website, but I'm having issues with the collapsable button. It is showing up fine, but not responding when clicked on.

It's probably something simple that I'm missing. ANy help would be wonderful!

```
<nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header ">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="col-md-4 logo">
                <h1><a href="index.php"></a></h1>
              </div><!--.logo-->
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="about" href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a class="products" href="#">Products</a></li>
                  <li><a class="technology" href="#">Technology</a></li>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </nav>
```

Comment: Works fine for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/5jy5A/.

Comment: I wonder why it's not clickable for me then...

Comment: are you loading bootsrtap script at all?

Comment: yes, everything else is working fine

Answer (score 0):

sorry I can't post comment.. but did you load jQuery? Because the click is handled there.

Comment: Yes, as I said everything else worked fine. I did figure out what was going on. It appears that because the logo is an h1, a block level element that is was covering the button even though it was appearing. Once I changed that to an inline element it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe covered with another block, so try giving that nav a higher z-index value.

```
<nav class="navbar-default" style="z-index:1;" role="navigation">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't the `z-index`, it was covered up because I had it styled to `float: left` and the next `div` was covering it up. `z-index` didn't fix it.

To fix it, the next sibling div had to be `display: inline-block;`.